# Does this IC have an optocoupler and a triac built into it?

Tags: ac, integrated-circuit, power-electronics, triac, phototriac

I am trying to use triac to switch an AC signal using a DC input on the gate terminal from a microcontroller. From my understanding you need a optocoupler when the DC to AC levels vary by a bit. So I am trying to find a triac that also has a built in optocoupler.

- [Digikey part link](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/triac-scr-output-optoisolators/904?s=N4IgTCBcDaIC4CcCWBDAxiAugXyA)
- [Part Data sheet](http://www.socle-tech.com/doc/IC%20Channel%20Product/Optoelectronic%20Components/Phototriac%20Coupler/s2s3_e.pdf)

I believe the one I have linked should work but I do not know if this one is actually the two built together in the same IC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Does this IC have a optocoupler and a triac built into it?*

The [data sheet](http://www.socle-tech.com/doc/IC%20Channel%20Product/Optoelectronic%20Components/Phototriac%20Coupler/s2s3_e.pdf) confirms this in several places. Two confirmations on page 1 of the linked data sheet: -

[image]

The data sheet also shows this symbol: -

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I was second guessing myself and I didn't want to order the wrong part. Also thank you for the speedy response.